# Jquery Lightslider will not cooperate with my tabbed layout. What am I missing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been using the JQuery LightSlider with absolutely zero issues for a couple of months now. However, we are restructuring our web product pages and there is something going on that I cannot figure out. I've gone through and ripped apart the CSS 5 times (I'm fairly certain that's where the problem lies), and had my back-end IT guru look through it.

Here's the problem: I've got the LightSlider situated within "tab 3" of my tabbed layout (which also functions with JQuery). I've gotten it to the point where the main image will display, along with the "next" and "previous" control arrows. However, the thumbnails will not display. Though if I inspect the page, the thumbnails show up and the main image disappears.

I do not have a JSFiddle for this, because it functions fine on it's own in a JSFiddle. It functions fine everywhere else. I have no issue providing the developmental web page: http://www.spilighting.com/emr/NPDP_SFAP.html

The problem tab is the "family" tab.

Comment: Looking trough the code, when I run the lightslider initialization code in the console the slider starts working hmm. I wouldn't use lightslider in any project though, I swear loyal to owl carousel :P

Answer (score 1):

i found solution for myself.

`jQuery('.tabs a').click(function(){ $('.sliders-item').resize(); });`

Answer (score 0):

I looked some more into it and lightslider is unable to load properly because the content of tab-3 is hidden when it's loading.

I found it out by doing the following steps:

1. Go to site and open a console while on tab 1
2. Load jQuery into console
3. Load lightslider into the console
4. Load lightslider initialization code from the header in the console

Result: slider doesn't work.

I repeated above but then opened the console while on tab 3 and the slider suddenly started working ;)

How to fix this?

Change your existing css and/or js to not hide tab 3.

Then instead hide tab 3 in the lightslider `onSliderLoad` function.

Or

You can also hide the tab content in a wrapper div with `overflow: hidden; height: 0;` and then set the wrapper div to `height: auto;` to show the tabs. This method makes sure the content is loaded in the dom as if it were shown without showing it or using any space.

Or

Use a more modern alternative to lightslider that works more reliable like owl-carousel :P

Comment: Thank you for looking into this further! Can I get the same "large image" with thumbnails functionality with Owl Carousel?

Comment: Yes, it even has the ability to change it's option on screen width (responsive). There are 2 versions, v1 and v2 beta, I'm currently using the beta version since that has some new options that are handy.

Comment: Went and downloaded Owl Carousel. Much better! Thank you!